# VB.Net two times split

Tags: vb.net, split

I'm am developing a app, and I have a question.
How can I do two times split?
What I mean is: |abcd,abcd|abcd,abcd
Now I want to split | and then I have two string, those two string I want
to split. How can I split those two strings?

With regards,

Martin de Groot

Comment: loop through the array result from the first split and split each element with the other delimiter you want to split on.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by splitting just once. See the following code.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim test = "|abcd,xyz|abcde,lmno|foo,123"
    Dim result = test.Split("|,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each item In result
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

All you have to do is place all your delimiters in the first argument in an array (or generate one as I have done), and then ensure you have no empty entries and you're good to go. The result will be one array with all the strings you want.

Answer (score -1):

Example

```
    Dim s As String = "|abcd,xyz|abcde,lmno|foo,123"
    Dim p() As String = s.Split(New Char() {"|"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim sp() As String
    For Each foo As String In p
        sp = foo.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Next
```